# GLUT Keyboard Events

Tags: c++, c, opengl, glut

I wrote program which simulates operations of selection sort. I added function myKeyboard to exit program, but because of using function sleep() to immitate animation myKeyboard works only after sorting is done. Is there any way to replace function sleep() such that i can exit program in the middle of sorting? This is code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>

using namespace std;

#define N 40

void run(void);
void display(int unused);
void selectionSort(int a[]);
void swap (int a[], int x, int y);
void mixArray (int a[]);
void myKeyboard( unsigned char key, int x, int y );
int i;
int T[N];


int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

glutInit(&argc,argv);
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH);
glutInitWindowSize(800, 800);
glutCreateWindow("Selection sort");
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glutKeyboardFunc(myKeyboard);
for (i = 0; i < N; i++) T[i] = i;
mixArray(T);
glutDisplayFunc(run);
glutTimerFunc(200,display,0);
glutMainLoop();
return 0;

}


void drawFigure(float x, float dx, float y, float dy, float z, float dz)
{
glBegin(GL_POLYGON);

glColor3f( 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f );

glVertex3f(  x + dx, y, z );
glVertex3f(  x + dx,  y + dy, z );
glVertex3f( x,  y + dy, z );
glVertex3f( x, y, z );

glEnd();


glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
glColor3f(   1.0f,  1.0f, 1.0f );

glVertex3f(  x + dx, y, z + dz );
glVertex3f(  x + dx,  y + dy, z + dz );
glVertex3f( x,  y + dy, z + dz );
glVertex3f( x, y, z + dz );
glEnd();


glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
glColor3f(  0.7f,  0.3f,  0.8f);

glVertex3f( x + dx, y, z );
glVertex3f( x + dx,  y + dy, z );
glVertex3f( x + dx,  y + dy,  z + dz );
glVertex3f( x + dx, y,  z + dz );
glEnd();


glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
glColor3f(   0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f );


glVertex3f( x, y,  z + dz );
glVertex3f( x,  y + dy,  z + dz );
glVertex3f( x,  y + dy, z );
glVertex3f( x, y, z );
glEnd();


glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
glColor3f(0.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f );

glVertex3f(  x + dx,  y + dy,  z + dz );
glVertex3f(  x + dx,  y + dy, z );
glVertex3f( x,  y + dy, z );
glVertex3f( x,  y + dy,  z + dz );
glEnd();


glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
glColor3f(1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f);

glVertex3f(x + dx, y, z );
glVertex3f(x + dx, y,  z + dz );
glVertex3f( x, y,  z + dz );
glVertex3f( x, y, z );
glEnd();
}


void display(int unused)
{
glLoadIdentity();

glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    glRotatef(-0.4f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f );
    glRotatef( 0.1f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f );
    drawFigure(-1.0f + i * 1.9f / N, 1.0f / N, -0.5f, float(T[i]) / N, -0.8f, 0.1f);

}

glFlush();
glutSwapBuffers();
}



void run()
{
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
glColor3f(0.5f, 0.2f, 0.7f);
selectionSort(T);
}


void selectionSort(int T[])
{
int minVal;
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    minVal = i;
    for (int j = i+1; j < N; j++)
    {
        if (T[j] < T[minVal])
        {
            minVal = j;
        }
    }

    swap(T, i, minVal);
    display(minVal);
}

}


void swap (int T[], int a, int b)
{
int tmp = T[a];
T[a] = T[b];
T[b] = tmp;
}

void mixArray(int T[])
{
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    swap(T, rand() % N, rand() % N);
}
}

void myKeyboard( unsigned char key, int x, int y )
{
if(key == 27)
{
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of running the sort inside of a glutDisplayFunc you can use glutTimerFunc to set up a function to be called every 200ms to do one step of the sort. This will allow keyboard events to be processed in between steps.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I tried to do it with the function glutTimerFunc and now I updated code in question. I deleted sleep and set display to be called 200ms after one step of sort but it's sorting it immidiately.

Comment: Your `run` function still does the sorting all at once. You need to do one step of the sorting algorithm each time your timer function is called.